# Using AFNetworking (1.3.3) AFHTTPClient and CSRF Tokens

Tags: objective-c, django, afnetworking, csrf

I have created an AFHTTPClient subclass as a web service interface to my friend's Django server. We're having great success except for 'DELETE' and 'POST' requests. His server requires a CSRF token, but I have no idea how to get that information or use that information in my AFHTTPClient. The Django server currently generates a CSRF when my application logs in (I believe in the header).

The failed attempt to perform a 'DELETE' or 'POST' generates this JSON response from his server: "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."

Ultimately, my question is: How do you manage CSRF tokens using AFNetworking (AFHTTPClient specifically)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The CSRF token is sent as a cookie with each HTTP response. You need to send it back with each POST/PUT/… request, in the `X-CSRFToken` header, just like it is done for AJAX requests. See also [the official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax).

Comment: This is understood, the real question is how to access and manage the X-CSRFToken header in the AFNetworking AFHTTPClient API for Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the csrf from cookies like so:

+(NSString* ) getCSRFFromCookie{

```
NSArray* cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookiesForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:API_SERVER_URL]];
NSLog(@"cookie csrf %@",    [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]);

NSString* strCookieValue=@"";
for(NSHTTPCookie* cookie in cookies) {
      if([cookie.name isEqualToString:@"csrftoken"])
        return cookie.value;
}

return strCookieValue;
```

}